# Creating new contact using people api + PHP

Tags: php, google-api

I can list all of the contacts in my account but when I try to create a new contact I get this error:

Image : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EffrnDMtYtnHpUyiz-SsjBo7dEnzNyKF/view?usp=sharing

Here I set the email and the use name to be added and when I got 403 "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

Code:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'People API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/client_secret.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/people.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts');

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
    $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
    } else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

        // Store the credentials to disk.
        if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
        printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
    }
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
    if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
        $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
    }
    return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);

$person = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Person();

$email = new Google_Service_PeopleService_EmailAddress();
$email->setValue('test@test.com');
$person->setEmailAddresses($email);

$name = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Name();
$name->setDisplayName('User de Test');
$person->setNames($name);

$exe = $service->people->createContact($person);

print_r($exe);
```

Comment: Have you verified that the user actually granted the required scope? See you are loading stored tokens there if available - were these created after the user granted this scope, or might they still be from before already?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure i deleted the part of adding the new user and list all of the contacts in my account and it works successfully
the error is triggered after executing this line $exe = $service->people->createContact($person);